# save eclipse workspace without restarting

Tags: eclipse, workspace

**save eclipse workspace without restarting **

Perhaps you've had this happen:

You customize your eclipse workspace and get it just right... then OS updates happen and the system reboots... during reboot eclipse gets forced off unexpectedly and doesn't save workspace.

When you come back, all your workspace custom settings are gone and your eclipse workspace is empty!

Is there a way to save the workspace without restarting eclipse? Maybe a way to make it auto save every 30 minutes if it sees changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible.  There is a long standing bug/request to address this. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2369

The following setting saves core state, but not UI state.

```
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace : Workspace save interval
```

Comment: Looks like progress is being made on adding this feature!